# Web Crawler C# .Net

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I'm not sure if this is actually called the web crawler, but this is what I'm trying to do.

I'm building a program in visual studio 2010 using C# .Net.

I want to find all the urls that has the same first part.

Say I have a homepage: `www.mywebsite.com`, and there are several subpage: `/tab1`, `/tab2`, `/tab3`, etc.

Is there a way to get a list of all urls that begins with `www.mywebsite.com`?

So by providing `www.mywebsite.com`, the program returns `www.mywebsite.com/tab1`, `www.mywebsite.com/tab2`, `www.mywebsite.com/tab3`, etc.

ps. I do not know how many total sub pages there are.

--edit at 12:04pm--

sorry for the lack of explanation.

I want to know how to write a crawler in C# that do the above task.

All I know is the main url `www.mywebsite.com`, and the goal is to find all its sub pages.

-- edit at 12:16pm--

Also, there is no links on the main page, the html is basically blank.

I just know that the subpages exist, but have no way to link to it except for providing the exact urls.

Comment: Consider refining your question to be more specific for where you're having problems in your implementation.

Comment: Please figure out what you actually asking for - your question ranges from "how to extract host name from url (i.e. using Url class)" to how to write web crawler by hand with parsing HTML using regular expression".

Comment: as a starting point see this article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13486/A-Simple-Crawler-Using-C-Sockets

Comment: if the hmtl is in blank in the home oage you should start to crawl the one that have links or other type of html tags you may want to follow. IE you can strat from www.mywebsite.com/tab2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you may consider to parse the html content in that page it doesn't really matter how is the structure of it you just need to think to grab the links  tags so the first you need do is

1- use an html parser I recommend [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) is a very mature html parser and it got a lot of features like linq to xml among others.

2- Parse the text using regular expressions in that way you'll be able to parse whatever html tag you want without involve too much code for it

3-  you need to think the depth of your links you want to crawl imagine the following scenario:

www.mywebsite.com/tab3 could contain www.mywebsite.com/tab3/link2 and www.mywebsite.com/tab3/link3 and so on so putting a limit is very important

4- you can create your own windows service and use web request to do the crawling or try to use a crawler from a third party, that depends on the purpose of what you wat to do I haven't use this but it seems ok to me, maybe it worth to take a look.

[Abot C# Web Crawler](https://github.com/sjdirect/abot)

Edit:

if the page is in blank you can crawl google with site:your domain.com as your primary pag and then extract the links from the actual domain instead of google or try to crawl the robots.txt from the site.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I just updated my question as you were answering. The html is blank so there were no links at all. I just know the sub pages exist but have no links to them, I have to type in the exact url.

Comment: @sora0419 if you don't know the sub-pages, then you can't just guess them nor can we help you figure out what they are. Find a link to the website which doesn't have a blank page and try to go from there, or check with google by searching `site:mywebsite.com` and see if there are any links there.

Comment: @sora0419 +1 I agree when you can cheat using a search engine if you don't know the internal urls, the only potential problem that I see is if that site isn't fully indexed on the search engine isn't going to work

Comment: What if I wanted to crawl a dynamic site that is the result of a search.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're crawling is internal links, then you will only find the sub-pages which the website links by itself. If there are any specific links which are exposed to other websites in some way and they're not linked internally, then you'll might miss them if you're only crawling the website in question.

There are several strategies:

- **Cheat:** if you're looking for all of the sub-pages of `turtlerescueleague.com`, then just Google `site:turtlerescueleague.com` and scrape the Google results. This will generally take care of the problem where the website may have pages which it doesn't link to itself but some other websites link to them.
- **Build a crawler:** you need to extract links from each HTML page, discard any external links, check if you've already visited a link, queue the new links in your queue of pages to visit and visit the page! Don't forget to do it all politely, i.e. comply with robots.txt :).